# Debug nasm Program Using gdb

Tags: assembly, gdb, nasm, x86-64

I have written a code to add the elements of an array in x64 Assembly Language (nasm). I want to debug the program using gdb. But when I run, it directly show me the answer. When I type 'n' it says that 'program is not running'. How can I actually see the whole debugging.
My source code is shown below:

```
global _start

section .data
    arr1 dq 0000000000000001h,0000000000000002h,0000000000000003h,0000000000000004h,0000000000000006h
    carry db 00
    msg1 db 'Addition Is:',10
    len1 equ $-msg1

section .bss
    addition resb 16



section .text
_start: 
    mov cl,4
    mov rsi,arr1
    mov rax,[rsi]

up: add rsi,8
    add rax,[rsi]

    jnc a1

    inc byte[carry]

a1: dec cl

    jnz up

    call display

    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,1
    mov rsi,msg1
    mov rdx,len1
    syscall

    add byte[carry],30h
    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,1
    mov rsi,carry
    mov rdx,1
    syscall

    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,1
    mov rsi,addition
    mov rdx,16
    syscall

    mov rax,60
    mov rdi,0
    syscall

display:
    mov rdi,addition
    mov cl,16

up1:
    rol rax,4
    mov rbx,rax
    and rax,0Fh
    cmp rax,09h

    ja dn1

    add rax,30h

    jmp dn

dn1:
    add rax,37h

dn: mov [rdi],rax
    mov rax,rbx
    inc rdi
    dec cl

    jnz up1

    ret
```

Comment: Use `ni` and also `nasm -f elf64 -F dwarf` and don't strip debug info. Oh yeah, and place a breakpoint at `_start` or wherever you want to stop, otherwise `run` will indeed just run the whole thing at once.

Comment: Jester can you elobrate your answer

Comment: Which part is unclear?

Comment: The breakpoint part, where and actually how can I add that.

Comment: In gdb, do `b _start` before you `run` the program.